# How to completely disable SELinux in Android L in the init.rc file

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, 4.4-kitkat, 5.0-lollipop, selinux

I want to disable SELinux at boot time for Android L or 5. The reason is because my daemon is not begin executed on boot when it should due to SELinux problems. I have the following in my **init.rc** file:

```
su 0 setenforce 0
service my_daemon /system/bin/my_daemon 
    class main     # Also tried: class core (but it didn't make a difference)
    user root
    group root
```

However, on boot, I use adb shell to check if SELinux is disabled (using `getenforce`) and it returns `Enforcing`. I want SELinux to be completely disabled on boot. If not completely disabled then at least `Permissive`.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

You have to disable selinux in kernel before compiling in your device configuration file, which is usually located in /kernel/.../arch/arm/config